# Efficient method to lower Matrix order in PHP

Tags: php, performance, matrix, determinants

I'm developing a determinant calculator in PHP

In the Matrix class I have created some functions, among them the function calc (order, matrix).
This function calls another one to lower the order of the array up to $ order = 3, and then executes the sarrus ($matriz) function.

> **Note:** This matrix variable will change whenever the order is lowered, ie the original matrix will be saved in another variable!

Well, I want to know the best method to lower the array order to 3, if possible a code example, I tried to use laplace but I got confused a lot in the loops I decided to give up for a while.

```
public function calc ($order, $matriz)
{
    // If the order equals 1: the element is the determinant
    if ($order == 1) {
        $ this->det = $matriz[0][0];
    }
    // If the order equals 2: call the @segOrder function
    else if ($order == 2) {
        segOrder($matriz);
    }
    // If the order is 3: call the function @sarrus
    else if ($order == 3) {
        sarrus($matriz);
    }
    // If the order is greater than 3: call the function @leaveOrder to lower the array order to 3 and then use @sarrus to have the determinant
    else if ($order > 3) {
        $matriz = lowerOrder($matriz, $order);
        sarrus($matriz);
    }
    return $this->det;
}
```

**The array layout:**

```
$matriz = array (
            array (1,2,3),
            array (4,5,6),
            array (7,8,9)
          );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking for something like this...

```
/**
 * Truncates rows and columns from an array of arrays (ignoring rows/columns beyond a certain index).
 *
 * The returned value will have numeric indexes regardless of what you pass in.
 *
 * @param array $matrix
 * @param int $row_cap
 * @param int $col_cap
 * @return array
 */
function matrix_slice( array $matrix, $row_cap = 3, $col_cap = 3 ) {
    return array_map( function( $vector ) use( $col_cap ){
        return array_slice( array_values( $vector ), 0, $col_cap );
    }, array_slice( array_values( $matrix ), 0, $row_cap ) );
}
```